# Matomo: report for single url

Tags: php, highcharts, matomo

I am new to Matomo, I would use it to generate report for specific url in my website.
For each page I needs all geoip graph, linechart, tables etc.

I watched demo and APIs but I didn’t find a way to do it with APIs or from panel demo (for a single page I can see only line charts in demo).

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [segment feature](https://matomo.org/docs/segmentation/) to filter everything by a query.

If you want a single URL, then you should add a segment for `Action URL is https://example.com/`

[image: add a new segment for "Action URL is THEURL"]

These segements (which can also be preprocessed can also be created via the SegmentEditor API: 
https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/reporting-api#SegmentEditor

In addition you can segment every API query on the fly by adding an `&segment=` parameter: 
https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/reporting-api-segmentation

Comment: Is possible to create segment via api and optain segmented HTML report via api?

Comment: I have expanded the answer

Comment: Perfect. Does it work with widgetize api module too?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer does not work anymore.

As of Matomo 3.12.0 the behavior of segments changed to show visits that started with a defined URL and all pages that the visitor visited subsequently.

The founder of Matomo recommends using goals as a substitute where you can create a goal to be triggered when a user visits a certain page URL or a page URL partial.

https://matomo.org/docs/tracking-goals-web-analytics/#create-a-goal

I couldn't find a way in the API to get a goal visits without conversion but I could be wrong. Below is the response to Goals.get

```
{
  "nb_conversions": 337,
  "nb_visits_converted": 327,
  "revenue": 14262.4,
  "conversion_rate": "8.09%",
  "nb_conversions_new_visit": 0,
  "nb_visits_converted_new_visit": 0,
  "revenue_new_visit": 0,
  "conversion_rate_new_visit": "0%",
  "nb_conversions_returning_visit": 337,
  "nb_visits_converted_returning_visit": 327,
  "revenue_returning_visit": 14262.4,
  "conversion_rate_returning_visit": "8.09%"
}
```

Related resources:
https://forum.matomo.org/t/filter-page-urls-by-segments/34859
https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/8450